# Microsoft sql server, проблемы с внешним ключом

Tags: sql, sql-server, сервер

```
CREATE TABLE STOCK(
    STOCK_NUM INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    DETAIL_ID INT NOT NULL,
    UNIT VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT ('pcs'),
    QUANTITY INT DEFAULT(0) CHECK(QUANTITY >= 0),
    LST_OPER_DATE DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT(GETDATE()),
    PRIMARY KEY (STOCK_NUM, DETAIL_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ACCOUNTING(
    STOCK_NUM INT NOT NULL,
    DOC_NUM INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    BUYER INT DEFAULT(0) CHECK(BUYER >= 0),
    ITEM_NUM INT DEFAULT(0) CHECK(ITEM_NUM >= 0),
    UNIT VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT ('PCS'),
    QUANTITY INT DEFAULT(0) CHECK(QUANTITY >= 0),
    SHIPPING_DATE DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT(GETDATE())
);
ALTER TABLE STOCK
ADD
    FOREIGN KEY (DETAIL_ID) REFERENCES detail (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNTING
ADD
    PRIMARY KEY (STOCK_NUM, DOC_NUM)
GO

ALTER TABLE ACCOUNTING
ADD
    FOREIGN KEY (STOCK_NUM) REFERENCES STOCK (STOCK_NUM)
GO
```

Все работает до момента, когда я пишу:

```
ALTER TABLE ACCOUNTING
    ADD
        FOREIGN KEY (STOCK_NUM) REFERENCES STOCK (STOCK_NUM)
    GO
```

Выводит ошибку:

> В таблице "STOCK", на которую имеются ссылки, отсутствуют первичные
>   или потенциальные ключи, соответствующие списку ссылающихся столбцов
>   во внешнем ключе "FK__ACCOUNTIN__STOCK__6E01572D"

Т.е. как я понимаю, он говорит, что STOCK_NUM не является первичным ключом, хотя я сделал смешанный первичный ключ: `PRIMARY KEY (STOCK_NUM, DOC_NUM)`

В чем ошибка, где я лажаю?

спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

У вас в таблице STOCK первичный ключ состоит из двух полей STOCK_NUM, DETAIL_ID, что само по себе очень странно, т.к. stock_num заведомо уникален и добавление каких либо полей к нему для обеспечения уникальности не требуется (в таблице ACCOUNTING у вас кстати та же проблема, не ясно зачем 2 поля в первичном ключе). Так вот, если в первичном ключе два поля, то все ссылки на таблицу должны так же идти по двум полям. Предполагается, что часть первичного ключа (одна колонка) сама по себе не уникальна и не может однозначно идентифицировать одну запись, а следовательно и ссылаться на нее одну невозможно.

Я думаю, что вам следует делать первичный ключи в обоих таблицах состоящие из одного поля, то которое identity. Первичные ключи состоящие более чем из одного поля используются редко и при этом в таких таблицах, где они бывают нужны колонок identity нет.

Comment: Вы говорите STOCK_NUM уникален, ибо там стоит identity ? 
2 поля в первичном ключе для следующего:
В запасах(STOCK) может храниться как одна деталь так и несколько, также и наоборот одна деталь может быть как в 1ом запасе так и во втором. И ключ по 2 полям делается для того, чтобы не было равнозначных полей, т.е. исключить возможность добавления 1, 1 и потом опять 1,1. Ну т.е. уникальность по 2 полям проверяется, ибо можно заполнить так: [1,2], [1,4], [1,1], [2,4] и.т.д.
Поэтому я и использовал PRIMARY KEY для 2 полей, иначе эти ошибки выявлять будет сложно

Comment: ну разве что ч-з триггеры, наверное, но при большом кол-ве данных я думая это будет нагружать систему

Comment: @KamilNHOT Но identity служит для того, что бы автоматически назначать полю новые, уникальные значения. И оно никогда не может назначить этому полю в двух записях значение 1. Кроме этого, вы сами никак не сможете изменить назначенное identity значение на свое. так что вы физически не сможете заполнить свою структуру так как говорите, потому что в одно из полей вы вообще не сможете вносить своих значений, оно будет заведомо уникально

Comment: @KamilNHOT  Если вам надо как вы говорите, то убирайте identity и сами ведите все. но тогда возникает вопрос, почему вы пытаетесь сослаться только по одному полю, если в уникальном ключе 2 поля. вот у вас есть записи [1,2], [1,4], а вы из другой таблицы пытаетесь сослаться только значением [1], но ссылка должна вести на заведомо уникальное поле, а 1 явно не уникальна, так что ссылка так же должна быть из двух полей

Comment: Да, это я понял и осознал, просто я сейчас не могу понять как это реализовать правильно

Comment: @KamilNHOT Если я правильно понимаю, что вам требуется у вас должны быть следующие таблицы: stock - это запасы, там только то что описывает их целиком, никаких деталей там нет. вторая таблица, видимо вами не показанная - это делали сами по себе, где первичный ключ тот detail_id, третья таблица - это детали в запасах, тут только два поля (ну может конечно больше если надо описать какую то особенность связи детали с запасами) sotck_id и detail_id, оба поля в первичном ключе этой таблицы и ссылаются на свои таблицы stock и detail

Comment: @KamilNHOT Ну а что касается неких accounting - то если им нужна связь только с запасами, то там ссылка на тот stock в котором уже нет никакого detail_id (т.к. он вынесен в другую таблицу)